# Getting data from input using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a value out of a `<input type='num'>` with JavaScript I am using the following code:

```
Choose a number between 1 and 5 <input type='num' name="input">

<button id="btn">Click me!</button>

<script>
    var input;

    document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
    input = document.getElementById('num');
        alert(input); //To check what value input has
</script>
```

This should get a value but I just get a null what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `getElementById('num')` Where's the element with that ID?

Comment: `document.getElementById()` is supposed to return `null` if no element *with the specified id* is found. But in any case the code shown is incomplete and won't run.

Comment: What does this have to do with databases?

Comment: use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nvtc7k68/

Comment: Sorry I am using this to get id's out of database's forgot to edit the name, Thanks for the help all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more than one problems with your code

1) You have to close the bracket of your function
it should be

```
 document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function(){
    input = document.getElementById('num');
        alert(input); //To check what value is outputted
}
```

2)

```
input = document.getElementById('num');
```

> The getElementById() method returns the element that has the ID
>   attribute with the specified value.

so ID attribute is essential here and in your code there is no ID attribute defined so you have to defined it first

like

```
<input type='number' id="num" name="input">
```

3) `document.getElementById('num');` does not return the value of input field 
it returns object 
so if you want value then use the following code

```
document.getElementById('num').value;
```

4) your `input type="number"`

for the desired output you can use following code

```
Choose a number between 1 and 5 <input type='number' name="input" id="myid">

<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
```

JS

```
    var myButton = document.getElementById("btn");
myButton.onclick = function()
{
         alert(document.getElementById("myid").value); //where does id come from?
}
```

The above method is pure JS if you need jquery method you can refer below

```
$( "#btn" ).click(function() {
  var input=$("#myid").val();
    alert(input)
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You have not defined your `id`. Also I guess your input type should be `number`.

```
<input type='number' name="input" id="num">
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^
```

And to `alert` its value you need to use

```
alert(input.value) //.value is used to get value of input
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById()` works on elements with `id` attribute. So, as you have not put `id` attribute in your `input` type, it is not able to find the element with `id=num`.
Just add `id="num"` in your `input` element and then you are good to go.