# Getting data out of a database with XMLHttpRequest, PDO, JSON, PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, pdo

So following my last [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803665/getting-data-from-input) I want to use the value that is submitted in the input tag to get the matching id in my database. I have created two files for it but I can't figure out how to link them.  Also note I made a database with a few values(id, firstname, etc.) and when the user fills in 1 I want it to display id 1 & the firstname.
This code is from the last question & I've added xmlhttp:

#### Input code

Choose a number between 1 and 5 
    
    Your info shall be shown here
    
    Click me!
    
    
        var myButton = document.getElementById('btn');
        myButton.onclick = function(){
        
        alert(document.getElementById('myid').value);
           
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
                    {
                        var dbText = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        document.getElementById('dbinfo').innerHTML = dbText;
                    }
                }
                 
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "LinkToDataFile", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");      
        }

That is what the user sees and the number is displayed correctly however I now need to link it to my file data.php which I have tried but it cannot get the value.

#### Data Code

```
<?php
    require_once('input_code');
    //Get the data from the database and echo them here
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databasename = "db_name";

    try
    {
        $connection = new PDO("mysql:host=".$servername.";dbname=".$databasename, $username, $password);
        $connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        
        
        $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT `id`, `firstname`, FROM `db_name` WHERE `id` = :myid"); //Here it needs to grab the value but it does not work.
        $statement->bindParam(':id', $id);
        $id = $_POST['id'];
                        
        $statement->execute();
        
        $result = $statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        $data = "";
        foreach($statement->fetchAll() as $key => $value)
        {
            $data .= $value['id']." | ".$value['firstname'];
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "The following error occurred : ".$e->getMessage();

    }

    echo $data;
    

?>
```

So what am I doing wrong? am I missing something obvious like the $id again or is it a series of errors, the only thing it does now is giving me an alert with the number.

Comment: Try running this in either Chrome or Firefox with the developer tools pane open.  Switch to the Networking tab and click on the ajax request.  See what it's showing as a response.  Are you seeing a PHP error message in the response?  Did the request even go through?

Comment: i supose that "input code" is something as index.php
1) replace LinkToDataFile with data.php
2) delete require_once('input_code');
3) $id = $_POST['id'] must be before $statement
4) and a little detail, you forgot send data in the ajax post
Add this line:
var id=document.getElementById('myid').value;
xmlhttp.send("id="+id);

Comment: @DanteJavier Thank you! by putting the $id before the statement and adding the send data to my script it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding a line and moving $id before $statement it is all fix thanks to [Dante Javier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4848837/dante-javier)

Input code

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");  //Under this add the following lines:
                var id = document.getElementById('myid').value; 
                xmlhttp.send("id="+id);
```

Data Code

```
$id = $_POST['id']; //Move this above the $statement = $connection->prepare.
```